# ReactJS - JavaScript: Filter function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ais

I am building a boat visualizer using [AISHub APIs](https://www.aishub.net/api). After inquiring the APIs I am able to obtain a json file with thousands of vessels, but I filter only the vessels I am interested in, and inject them into a table on a webpage. The API gives the following fileds: `[NAME, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, others...]`. The most important parameters I am using for the filtering are : `NAME` and `MMSI` (whereas there could be multiple vessels with same `NAME`, there cannot be two vessels with the same `MMSI` number because it is unique).

**The problem** I have is that the `filter` function does not seem to have the proper behavior.
In fact it does not filter uniquely for that specific `NAME` and/or `MMSI` and I end up having multiple vessels with same `NAME` and with different `MMSI`. Also the vessel that should appear, it does not, despite I hard-coded the `NAME` and `MMSI` for that specific vessel.
Which is not explainable as I hard-coded those numbers to be specifically filtered.

Below the code I am using for the filtering search:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require('axios');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const myCache = new NodeCache();

let hitCount = 0;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

const mmsiOfInterest = [
    '367029520', // ok -> MICHIGAN
    '366909730', // ok -> JP BOISSEAU
    '367128570', // ok -> DELAWARE BAY
    '366744010', // ok -> ATLANTIC SALVOR
    // Other MMSI numbers .....
];


const shipNamesOfInterest = [
    'MICHIGAN',
    'JP BOISSEAU',
    'DELAWARE BAY',
    'ATLANTIC SALVOR',
    // Other NAMES....
]

router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    const allData = myCache.get('allData');

    if (!allData) {
        hitCount++;
        console.log(`hit ${hitCount} number of times`);
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=MY_KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=0&latmin=11.42&latmax=58.20&lonmin=-134.09&lonmax=-52.62'
        );

        const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
        console.log(data);

        const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(
            (ship) => mmsiOfInterest.includes(ship.MMSI) || shipNamesOfInterest.includes(ship.NAME)
        );
        myCache.set('allData', shipsOfInterest, 70);
        res.send(data);
        return;
    }

    console.log('this is the data:', allData);
    res.send(allData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Also below a typical `JSON` response from the API:

```
{"MMSI":225342000,"TIME":"2020-01-26 01:45:48 GMT","LONGITUDE":1.43912,"LATITUDE":38.91523,"COG":339.9,"SOG":0,"HEADING":297,"ROT":0,"NAVSTAT":0,"IMO":9822449,"NAME":"ILLETAS JET","CALLSIGN":"EAVX","TYPE":40,"A":4,"B":25,"C":4,"D":4,"DRAUGHT":0,"DEST":"IBIZA","ETA":"00-00 00:00"}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I tried different combination with the `filter` function and I tried to filter by `MMSI`, which is supposed to be unique for each vessel, but still I end up with vessels with same `NAME` and different `MMSI` (despite I hard-coded the `MMSI`...I don't understand):

```
const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(
                (ship) => mmsiOfInterest.includes(ship.MMSI)
            );
```

After I tried filtering by `NAME`, but that does not work either:

```
const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(
                (ship) => shipNamesOfInterest.includes(ship.NAME)
            );
```

**EDIT 2**

```
router.get('/hello', async function(req, res, next) {
    //
    const allData = myCache.get('allData');

    if (!allData) {
        hitCount++;
        console.log(`hit ${hitCount} number of times`);
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=KEY&format=1&output=json&compress=0&latmin=11.42&latmax=58.20&lonmin=-134.09&lonmax=-52.62'
        );

        // console.log(data);
        const { metaData, ships } = data;
        const set = new Set();
        const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter((ship) => {
            if (set.has(ship.MMSI)) return false;
            set.add(ship.MMSI);
            return true;
        });
        myCache.set('allData', shipsOfInterest, 70);
        res.send(data);
        return;
    }

    console.log('this is the data:', allData);
    res.send(allData);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Below the error:

[image: error]

I don't know if the `filter` function can get a better result if organized in a different way. I thought that this could have been a very good way to organize the search and don't understand what it does not work.
Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Comment: By "hard-coding the MMSI, you're saying that something like the following code returns ships with multiple MMSI values? `const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(ship => ship.MMSI === '367029520' );`

Comment: Also, can you provide a small example of the JSON that's returned by the API? Their website only shows an XML formatted example.

Comment: I didn't try that straight as I hard coded an association map: `mmsiOfInterest` is matching exactly `shipNamesOfInterest`. I could try that though. Also yes let me post a `JSON` format typical example.

Comment: Ok, posted the `JSON` response

Comment: With your new error, you should try wrapping your `get` in a "try/catch" block to stop execution if your API returns an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of `if` statement you do `res.send(data)`, which is basically the data you received from the API. Instead, you need to `res.send(shipsOfInterest)`; Also, change the format of `mmsiOfInterest` list from strings to numbers, because you receive numbers from the API.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you made mistake while using the shorthand assignment. Use {} instead of [].

Instead of:

```
  const [ metaData, ships ] = data;
```

try:

```
  const { metaData, ships } = data;
```

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. Unfortunately if I switch with your suggestion nothing works, and the function does not even filter any vessels. I though about doing that but never tried until now.

Comment: Ok I updated the question carrying your suggestion too. There is **EDIT 2** with the provided code and a [print screen](https://i.imgur.com/9ffBBv9.png) of the error. Is that useful?

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understand you the filtered list to contain the records with unique `MMSI` value. So, what you need to do is:

```
const uniqueMMSI = new Set();
const shipsOfInterest = ships.filter(
  (ship) => {
    if (set.has(ship.MMSI)) return false;
    set.add(ship.MMSI);
    return true;
  }
);
```

I hope I understood your question :)

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I tried your solution and it works partially as it starts filtering but it stops throwing: `(node:16461) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: set is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, please rename `uniqueMMSI` to `set`.

Comment: No worries, do you mean this: `const uniqueMMSI = new set();`

Comment: Ok a small progress. It started filtering but it stopped throwing this error: `(node:17284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. I will make a print screen of the error.

Comment: @Flavin explained why it is undefined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436602/5847921

Comment: I'd also propose to check the contents of data by `console.log(data)` because I am not sure that your destructuring is correct.

Comment: Ok I updated the question. There is **EDIT 2** with the provided suggestion and a [print screen](https://i.imgur.com/9ffBBv9.png) of the error. Is that useful?

Comment: You have this error because there is no `ships` field in `data`. Can you `console.log(data)` and tell me what is the result?

Comment: Yes, ok [this is the printscreen](https://i.imgur.com/gkJxG5H.png) of the `console.log(data + 'ERROR IS:');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208657/discussion-between-vyacheslav-palamar-and-emanuele).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MMSI is coming in as a numeric value, while your comparison array is holding strings. How about using an array of integers for your comparison?

```
const mmsiOfInterest = [
    367029520,
    366909730, 
    367128570, 
    366744010, 
    // Other MMSI numbers .....
];
```

Comment: That was another option I didn't try. I just tried it and it started filtering but stopped with the error: `(node:17733) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: Ok I updated the question. There is **EDIT 2** with the provided suggestion and a [print screen](https://i.imgur.com/9ffBBv9.png) of the error. Is that useful?